# How to create a Gnome icon to launch a link to a shell script?

Tags: gnome, scripts, launcher, icons

I'm trying to install **ModelSim from Altera** in ubuntu Gnome 14.04LTS running Gnome 3.12.2.
It is hard: things needed quite a lot of tweaking, but finally I managed to launch the software **from a link to a script** from the `~altera/ecc/ecc/bin/` folder.

Now I'd like to create a desktop icon in gnome. 
I'm able to run the program simply typing its name

```
vsim
```

either into its folder or in my home (I added it to the PATH).

But I can't get a working modelsim.desktop file.
Here's my attempt:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ModelSim 
Exec=/home/abet/altera/13.0sp1/modelsim_ase/bin/vsim
Icon=/usr/share/icons/modelsim.png
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
```

What I get is:

> There was an error launching the application.

The file I want to run looks like this in nautilus.

[image]

Trying to launch the script pointed by the link (which is in another folder) in the terminal I get:

```
cd /home/abet/altera/13.0sp1/modelsim_ase/ && ./vco
linux
```

And ModelSim doesn't start.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it launch if you run `/home/abet/altera/13.0sp1/modelsim_ase/bin/vsim` in terminal?

Comment: This `vsim` file seems to be a link. Try using the actual path to the script.

Comment: The screenshot already shows the (relative!) link target, but from the terminal you can get this information with `file /path/to/link`, `stat /path/to/link` or even `ls -l /path/to/link` by the way.

Comment: I edited the post to show what happens if I try to launch the vco script directly.

Answer (score 0):

The actual path to the script seems to be

```
/home/abet/altera/13.0sp1/modelsim_ase/vco
```

so try

```
Exec=/home/abet/altera/13.0sp1/modelsim_ase/vco
```

in your `modelsim.desktop` file.

Comment: Added the terminal output in the question. From Gnome I can't see anything: I press the icon and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

In the `.desktop` file just add this line:

```
Terminal=true
```

and it will be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ModelSim 
Exec="/home/manendra/intelFPGA/20.1/modelsim_ase/bin/vsim"
Icon=/usr/share/icons/ModelSim.png
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
Terminal=true
```

This is the working solution for me.